# Type hinting / annotation (PEP 484) for numpy.ndarray

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, type-hinting, python-typing

Has anyone implemented type hinting for the specific [`numpy.ndarray`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.ndarray.html) class?

Right now, I'm using [`typing.Any`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#the-any-type), but it would be nice to have something more specific.

For instance if the NumPy people added a [type alias](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#type-aliases) for their [array_like](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.creation.html#converting-python-array-like-objects-to-numpy-arrays) object class. Better yet, implement support at the [dtype](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.dtypes.html) level, so that other objects would be supported, as well as [ufunc](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/ufuncs.html).

Comment: I don't recall seeing any use of Python3 type annotation in SO `numpy` questions or answers.

Comment: https://pypi.python.org/pypi/plac can make use of Py3 annotations - to populate an `argparse` parser.  For Py2, it uses decorators to create a similar `annocation` database.

Comment: `typing` is new to Py 3.5.  Many `numpy` users still work with Py2.  I have 3.5 on my system, but I don't have `numpy` installed for it.  `numpy` developers are not going to add features for the cutting edge of Python  (with the exception of the `@` operator)

Comment: @hpaulj, can you cite your source for the last comment? I'm not sure where I should go to interact with the Numpy maintainers... it could very well be that integrating other 'advanced' Python features would be popular.

Comment: `numpy` is maintained on a `github` repository.  Look at the `issues` and `pull requests`; sign up and submit your own issue.  There may be another forum for discussing development issues, but most I look at the `github` issues.

Comment: For anyone looking into the issue - it looks like there's a relevant solution here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52839427/numpy-type-hints-in-python-pep-484

Comment: There is now an open [issue](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/issues/7370) in the numpy github repository regarding type hinting / annotation for numpy types.

Comment: > There is now...
@Jasha this ticket was opened by me, the OP, 4.5 years ago.

Answer (score 71, accepted):

## Update

Check recent numpy versions for a new `typing` module

https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/typing.html#module-numpy.typing

### dated answer

It looks like `typing` module was developed at:

https://github.com/python/typing

The main `numpy` repository is at

https://github.com/numpy/numpy

Python bugs and commits can be tracked at

http://bugs.python.org/

The usual way of adding a feature is to fork the main repository, develop the feature till it is bomb proof, and then submit a pull request. Obviously at various points in the process you want feedback from other developers.  If you can't do the development yourself, then you have to convince someone else that it is a worthwhile project.

`cython` has a form of annotations, which it uses to generate efficient `C` code.

---

You referenced the `array-like` paragraph in `numpy` documentation.  Note its `typing` information:

> A simple way to find out if the object can be converted to a numpy array using array() is simply to try it interactively and see if it works! (The Python Way).

In other words the `numpy` developers refuse to be pinned down.  They don't, or can't, describe in words what kinds of objects can or cannot be converted to `np.ndarray`.

```
In [586]: np.array({'test':1})   # a dictionary
Out[586]: array({'test': 1}, dtype=object)

In [587]: np.array(['one','two'])  # a list
Out[587]: 
array(['one', 'two'], 
      dtype='<U3')

In [589]: np.array({'one','two'})  # a set
Out[589]: array({'one', 'two'}, dtype=object)
```

For your own functions, an annotation like

```
def foo(x: np.ndarray) -> np.ndarray:
```

works.  Of course if your function ends up calling some `numpy` function that passes its argument through `asanyarray` (as many do), such an annotation would be incomplete, since your input could be a `list`, or `np.matrix`, etc.

---

When evaluating this question and answer, pay attention to the date.  484 was a relatively new PEP back then, and code to make use of it for standard Python still in development.  But it looks like the links provided are still valid.

Comment: What software, editor or interpreter are you using that makes use of `annotations`?  As best I know, in plain Python 3, a function gets a `__annotations__` dictionary, but the interpreter does nothing with it.

Comment: Do you want `typing` annotations added to existing `numpy` functions (including `np.array`), or just types that would make it easier to add annotations to your own functions?

Comment: I've marked this answer as the accepted one, but just for completeness, I was going for the latter (type hinting in my own code, which uses Numpy).

I'm all for Duck Typing, but when you **can** provide static type information, I don't see why you wouldn't, if only for static code analysis (PyCharm does warn about incompatible types).

Thanks, @hpaulj!

Comment: Since, typing module simply provides hints, I have created two helper labels purely for readability and note it doesn't pass mypy static type checks.                                         ```def Vector(np_arr):
    return np_arr.ndim == 1

def Matrix(np_arr):
    return np_arr.ndim > 1
 ``` .  Hope, it helps someone.

Comment: What about the shape?  I can add hints like def blah() -> np.ndarray(785):   But I can't can't add a second dimension like -> np.ndarray(785, 10).   Having a shape hint is very helpful and brings clarity to multiple functions in my code that produce arrays of varying dimensionality.

Comment: @Steve3p0 support for shapes is work-in-progress in python (https://peps.python.org/pep-0646/) as well as numpy (https://github.com/numpy/numpy/issues/16544)

Answer (score 85):

Numpy 1.21 includes a `numpy.typing` module with an `NDArray` generic type.

---

###### From the [Numpy 1.21 docs](https://numpy.org/doc/1.21/reference/typing.html#numpy.typing.NDArray):

> ```py
> numpy.typing.NDArray = numpy.ndarray[typing.Any, numpy.dtype[+ScalarType]]
> ```
>
> A generic version of `np.ndarray[Any, np.dtype[+ScalarType]]`.
>
> Can be used during runtime for typing arrays with a given dtype and unspecified shape.
>
> **Examples:**
>
> ```py
> >>> import numpy as np
> >>> import numpy.typing as npt
>
> >>> print(npt.NDArray)
> numpy.ndarray[typing.Any, numpy.dtype[+ScalarType]]
>
> >>> print(npt.NDArray[np.float64])
> numpy.ndarray[typing.Any, numpy.dtype[numpy.float64]]
>
> >>> NDArrayInt = npt.NDArray[np.int_]
> >>> a: NDArrayInt = np.arange(10)
>
> >>> def func(a: npt.ArrayLike) -> npt.NDArray[Any]:
> ...     return np.array(a)
> ```

As of 2022-09-05, support for shapes is still a work in progress per [numpy/numpy#16544](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/issues/16544).

Comment: I am  just wondering what if I use ndarray rather than NDArray in type hinting ? Is there any fundamental difference ?

Comment: Looking at [the definition of `NDarray`](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/b235f9e701e14ed6f6f6dcba885f7986a833743f/numpy/typing/_generic_alias.py#L201-L208), it seems that (1) there *is* a difference at runtime (as `NDArray` is a generic alias while `ndarray` is a class), and (2) at type-checking time (e.g. when using mypy, pyright, etc) there should by no difference between `NDarray[Foo]` and `np.ndarray[Any, np.dtype[Foo]]`.

Comment: Is there a way to define the number of dimensions (Vector, Matrix, 3 dimensions, etc...)?

Comment: No, Numpy does not support that currently. There are long term efforts to support such shape hints in the python ecosystem, e.g. [PEP 646](https://peps.python.org/pep-0646/) was recently introduced in python3.11. I suspect that Numpy will likely move towards eventual support of shape hints / number-of-dimension hints via PEP 646, but it will likely take a long time to implement and roll out. In the meantime, there are 3rd party libraries such as [nptyping](https://github.com/ramonhagenaars/nptyping) that provide type hints for Numpy with support for shape hints.

Comment: What's the first argument to the `np.ndarray[...]` type hint and why is it `Any` in all the examples?

Comment: I believe the first argument is intended for future use as a "shape annotation," where you'd hint to the type checker about what dimensions you expect the array to have. The examples use `Any` because numpy has not yet implemented support for such annotations.

Comment: Not sure if this question is covered above already, but it's not clear to me: does it matter whether I use `npt.NDArray` or np.ndarray` as a type hint. If so, when should I use which?

Comment: @db_ For humans and static type checkers reading the code, the type hint `arr: NDArray[np.float64]` gives more information than does `arr: ndarray`. This is potentially advantageous.

Comment: `np.ndarray[Any, np.dtype[+ScalarType]]` is unclear to me - I don't know what the `+` stands for there, nor `ScalarType` for that matter.

Answer (score 33):

At my company we've been using:

```
from typing import TypeVar, Generic, Tuple, Union, Optional
import numpy as np

Shape = TypeVar("Shape")
DType = TypeVar("DType")

class Array(np.ndarray, Generic[Shape, DType]):
    """  
    Use this to type-annotate numpy arrays, e.g. 
        image: Array['H,W,3', np.uint8]
        xy_points: Array['N,2', float]
        nd_mask: Array['...', bool]
    """
    pass

def compute_l2_norm(arr: Array['N,2', float]) -> Array['N', float]:
    return (arr**2).sum(axis=1)**.5

print(compute_l2_norm(arr = np.array([(1, 2), (3, 1.5), (0, 5.5)])))
```

We actually have a MyPy checker around this that checks that the shapes work out (which we should release at some point).  Only thing is it doesn't make PyCharm happy (ie you still get the nasty warning lines):

[image]

Comment: any updates on the MyPy checker? would love to integrate it to my env

Comment: This is good stuff, thanks for sharing. It seems, however, that the nptyping package (https://github.com/ramonhagenaars/nptyping) considerably generalizes this.

Comment: I still find myself using this version over nptyping for documentation purposes, because I find a`Array['2,2',int]` easier to type than `NDArray[Shape["2, 2"], Int]`, and you can give meaning via what you name dimensions, e.g. `BGRImageArray = Array['H,W,3', 'uint8']` makes it clear that the first dimension is height.  That said, if you actually intend to use mypy for type checking, definitely go for `nptyping`.

Comment: This sort of reinvents the wheel (albeit not a very good one), with numpy.typing being a thing.

Comment: @amka66 Puzzlingly, [nptyping doesn't currently seem to allow Mypy to check shape mismatches](https://github.com/ramonhagenaars/nptyping/issues/88), so in that sense it is worse than the solution in this answer if you don't need support for all that extra stuff like recarrays...

Comment: @usernumber numpy.typing doesn't currently support shape annotations/checking. This solution does.

Answer (score 11):

[nptyping](https://github.com/ramonhagenaars/nptyping) adds lots of flexibility for specifying numpy type hints.

Comment: nptyping is a life changer.. it really solved my problems when typing numpy arrays. It works great with unittests when one needs to verify the instance type, shape, etc. I highly recommend using it!

Answer (score -1):

What i did was to just define it as

> Dict[Tuple[int, int], TYPE]

So for example if you want an array of floats you can do:

`a = numpy.empty(shape=[2, 2], dtype=float)  # type: Dict[Tuple[int, int], float]`

This is of course not exact from a documentation perspective, but for analyzing correct usage and getting proper completion with pyCharm it works great!

Comment: this is worse than using `np.ndarray` as a type

Comment: @JulesG.M., may I know what's the difference of using np.array and NDArray as a type? if you have a quick answer.

Comment: this is an old comment, from before NDArray came to exist @Jiadong. NDArray is better now because it has tools to also indicate the `dtype` of the array