# Numpy type hints in Python (PEP 484)

Tags: python, numpy, pep

I would like to add type hints to a method that takes a numpy array as an input, and returns a string. This numpy array contains floats so I tried:

```
import numpy as np
def foo(array: np.ndarray[np.float64]) -> str:
```

But it will not work due to a `TypeError: 'type' object is not subscriptable`.

I found [this](https://github.com/numpy/numpy-stubs) but could not follow the discussions!

Comment: It looks like that link is an experimental package that is still in development. Have you looked at the built-in [typing](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html) library?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35673895/type-hinting-annotation-pep-484-for-numpy-ndarray is an answer I gave several years back.  484 type hints were experimental then, and may still be.  And https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38005633/pep-484-type-annotations-with-own-types

Comment: There is now an open [issue](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/issues/7370) in the numpy github repository regarding type hinting / annotation for numpy types.

Answer (score 16):

Check out [nptyping](https://github.com/ramonhagenaars/nptyping). It offers type hints for numpy arrays.

In your case, you would end up with:

```py
from nptyping import NDArray, Float64

def foo(array: NDArray[Float64]) -> str:
    ...
```

You can check your instances as well:

```py
import numpy as np
from nptyping import NDArray, Float64

arr = np.array([[1.0, 2.0],
                [3.0, 4.0],
                [5.0, 6.0]])

isinstance(arr, NDArray[(3, 2), Float64])  # True.

# Or if you don't want to check the dimensions and their sizes:
isinstance(arr, NDArray[Float64])  # Also True.
```

Comment: Project status?

Comment: It is alive. There haven't been any feature requests or bug reports recently though.

Comment: Would be great to also have visibility into the `ndarray` methods such as `argmax`, `shape` , ..

Comment: Support/connection to mypy would be great in this project, i.e. so that if I wrote 
```arr: NDArray[(3, 1), Any] = np.array([[1.0, 2.0], [3.0, 4.0]])``` 
I would get type error through mypy.

Comment: Similarly, PyCharm has trouble connecting NDArray to np.ndarray

Comment: This doesn't work with pycharm

Answer (score 2):

As I explained in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68916893/typeerror-numpy-dtypemeta-object-is-not-subscriptable/72648543#72648543), there is a little trick with wrapping `numpy` types with `'` :

```py
import numpy as np
from typing import Any

def foo(array: 'np.ndarray[Any , np.dtype[np.float64]]') -> str:
    ...
```

This works correctly for Pylance type checker on VSCode, and gives no error while execute.

[image]

Note that `np.ndarray` expects 2 arguments, the first one is the shape of the array, the second the dtype of the data inside the array. More info in the [doc](https://numpy.org/devdocs/reference/arrays.dtypes.html#arrays-dtypes).

This method is also better than using `nptyping` since it works for all types, not just the ones described by `nptyping`. As of now, for instance, there is no support for `tuple`. [see related issue](https://github.com/ramonhagenaars/nptyping/issues/80).

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72649220/strongly-type-array-numpy-ndarray-of-matplotlib-axes-from-plt-subplots) is another interesting example I gave