# TypeError: 'numpy._DTypeMeta' object is not subscriptable

Tags: python, numpy, type-hinting, python-typing, type-alias

I'm trying to type hint a numpy `ndarray` like this:

```
RGB = numpy.dtype[numpy.uint8]
ThreeD = tuple[int, int, int]

def load_images(paths: list[str]) -> tuple[list[numpy.ndarray[ThreeD, RGB]], list[str]]: ...
```

but at the first line when I run this, I got the following error:

```
RGB = numpy.dtype[numpy.uint8]
TypeError: 'numpy._DTypeMeta' object is not subscriptable
```

How do I type hint a `ndarray` correctly?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Numpy type hints in Python (PEP 484)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52839427/numpy-type-hints-in-python-pep-484)

Comment: @blorgon It doesn't behave like the way it's documented. I wanted to have a `ndarray` that had 3 dimensions of any size and dtype of `int8`, so I wrote it as `nptyping.NDArray[(typing.Any, typing.Any, typing.Any), nptyping.Int8]`, but it gave me this error: `Expected class type but received "None"`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It turns out that strongly type a numpy array is not straightforward at all. I spent a couple of hours to figure out how to do it properly.

A simple method that do not add yet another dependency to your project is to use a trick described [here](https://github.com/python/typing/issues/410). Just wrap numpy types with with `'`:

```py
import numpy
import numpy.typing as npt
from typing import cast, Type, Sequence
import typing

RGB: typing.TypeAlias = 'numpy.dtype[numpy.uint8]'
ThreeD: typing.TypeAlias = tuple[int, int, int]
NDArrayRGB: typing.TypeAlias = 'numpy.ndarray[ThreeD, RGB]'

def load_images(paths: list[str]) -> tuple[list[NDArrayRGB], list[str]]: ...
```

The **trick is to use single-quotes** to avoid the infamous `TypeError: 'numpy._DTypeMeta' object is not subscriptable` when Python tries to interpret the `[]` in the expression. This trick is well handled for instance by VSCode Pylance type-checker:

[image]

Notice that the colors for types are respected and that the execution gives no error.

#### Note about `nptyping`

As suggested by @ddejohn, one can use [nptyping](https://github.com/ramonhagenaars/nptyping). Just install the package: `pip install nptyping`. However, as of now (16 June 2022), there is no Tuple type defined in `nptyping` so you won't be able to prefectly type you code that way. I have [open a new issue](https://github.com/ramonhagenaars/nptyping/issues/80) so maybe in the future it will work.

###### edits

Turns out there is a different way to express a `tuple` as a `nptyping.Shape` as answered by [ramonhagenaars](https://github.com/ramonhagenaars), which is also elegant:

```py
from nptyping import NDArray, Shape, UInt8

# A 1-dimensional array (i.e. 1 RGB color).
RGBArray1D = NDArray[Shape["[r, g, b]"], UInt8]

# A 2-dimensional array (i.e. an array of RGB colors).
RGBArrayND = NDArray[Shape["*, [r, g, b]"], UInt8]

def load_images_trick(paths: list[str]) -> tuple[list[RGBArrayND], list[str]]: ...
```

However, this solution is not well supported by VSCode Pylance, an I get an error suggestion for Shape:

```
Expected class type but received "Literal"
  "Literal" is not a class
  "Literal" is not a classPylancereportGeneralTypeIssues
Pylance(reportGeneralTypeIssues)
```

[image]

Comment: Does the part with `ThreeD` actually work? I was trying to limit the `ndarray` to 3-dimensional only. That's why I wrote `tuple[int, int, int]` but looking back I don't think it would work.

Comment: There is not "real" limitation in one situation or another. Typing is just something useful on the developer perspective, not really at code execution unless you use `assert(isinstance())`. I kept your custom types for clarity but you can concatenate everything if you prefer. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 10):

I had a similar issue with my opencv2 library, which I by upgrading numpy
`pip install numpy --upgrade`

Answer (score 6):

```
pip install numpy==1.20.0
```

will work

Answer (score 1):

The command `np.ndarray[...]` raises an exception for certain versions of numpy.
The command, `typing.TypeAlias` used in the accepted answer also raises an exception for certain versions of python, e.g. [[1](https://github.com/mkleehammer/pyodbc/issues/1186)].
I had this issue while collaborating with colleagues with different OS and different python versions.
They updated `numpy` but the error persisted, so I came up with this solution that worked for all of us and still checks for type errors in my machine:

```py
from typing import TYPE_CHECKING

if TYPE_CHECKING:
    from typing import TypeAlias
else:
    TypeAlias = "TypeAlias"

NDArrayInt: "TypeAlias" = "np.ndarray[int, np.dtype[np.number]]"
NDArrayFloat: "TypeAlias" = "np.ndarray[float, np.dtype[np.number]]"
DiscreteMechanism: "TypeAlias" = "Callable[[NDArrayInt], NDArrayInt]"
```