# Precise type annotating array (numpy.ndarray) of matplotlib Axes from plt.subplots()

Tags: python, matplotlib, python-typing, pylance

I wanted to have no errors while using VSCode Pylance type checker.

How to type the `axs` correctly in the following code:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
fig, axs = plt.subplots(2, 2)
```

In the image below, you can see that Pylance on VSCode is detecting an error.

[image]

Comment: "strongly typing" is not the correct terminology here, you just mean *typing*, really. either "type hinting" or "type annotating". Strong typing is a loosely-defined term that applies to languages (python is generally considered strongly typed).

Comment: I think you wanted to say that Python is NOT strongly typed. Actually to me, sure, Python by design is not a strongly typed language. However the same way that VSCode Pylance type-checker expresses it, there are several "levels" of typing in python. For instance, stating some `var` is a `list` is type hinting. Saying it is a `list[plt.Axes] | None` is strongly typing. But here we are just debating about terms. In the end, it's only type hinting. Hope you understand why I chose that term here.

Comment: no, I mean that it *is* strongly typed.  You seem to be confusing the expression "strong typing" with "static typing". Python is *not* statically typed (although, nowadays it can be with type-hints and third-party static type checkers like `mypy` and `pyright`). But Python has always been considered strongly typed. Not all statically typed languages are strongly typed either, e.g. C is generally considered weakly typed

Comment: Ok you are right. I will remembrer that thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out that strongly typing the `axs` variable is not straightforward at all and requires to understant well how to type `np.ndarray`.

See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68916893/typeerror-numpy-dtypemeta-object-is-not-subscriptable/72648543#72648543) and [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52839427/numpy-type-hints-in-python-pep-484/72648749#72648749) for more details.

The simplest and most powerful solution is to wrap `numpy.ndarray` with `'` characters, in order to avoid the infamous TypeError: 'numpy._DTypeMeta' object is not subscriptable when Python tries to interpret the [] in the expression.

An example:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import numpy.typing as npt
import seaborn as sns
from typing import cast, Type, Sequence
import typing 

sns.set() 

# Some example data to display
x = np.linspace(0, 2 * np.pi, 400)
y = np.sin(x ** 2)

fig, axs = plt.subplots(
    2, 2, 
    figsize=(12, 10) # set graph size
)

# typechecking operation
NDArrayOfAxes: typing.TypeAlias = 'np.ndarray[Sequence[Sequence[plt.Axes]], np.dtype[np.object_]]'
axs = cast(np.ndarray, axs)

axs[0, 0].plot(x, y)
axs[0, 0].set_title("main")
axs[1, 0].plot(x, y**2)
axs[1, 0].set_title("shares x with main")
axs[1, 0].sharex(axs[0, 0])
axs[0, 1].plot(x + 1, y + 1)
axs[0, 1].set_title("unrelated")
axs[1, 1].plot(x + 2, y + 2)
axs[1, 1].set_title("also unrelated")
fig.tight_layout()
```

Which is well detected by Pylance and runs correctly:

[image]

Comment: what is the use of the line `NDArrayOfAxes: typing.TypeAlias = 'np.ndarray[Sequence[Sequence[plt.Axes]], np.dtype[np.object_]]'`? By removing this line, the result seems to be the same.

Comment: This approach removes the warnings. But Pylance does not recognizes `plot`, `set_title`, etc... as  `Axes` methods. [wschella's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74197401/9761768) seems to do that.

Answer (score 1):

For reasons I don't aim to understand, the [currently accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72649221/6182278) kept giving warnings, errors, and lacked successful type inference in my setup.

What I did instead was this, which allows slicing, and allowed Pylance to understand that `.plot` is `Axes.plot`:

```py
from typing import TypeVar, Generic, cast

import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.axes import Axes

# Little helper class, which is only used as a type.
DType = TypeVar("DType")
class Array(np.ndarray, Generic[DType]):
    def __getitem__(self, key) -> DType:
        return super().__getitem__(key) # type: ignore

# Force assign the type, which is correct for most intents and purposes
fig, _axs = plt.subplots(2, 2)
axs = cast(Array[Axes], _axs)

# Use as an ndarray of Axes
axs[0,0].plot(...)
```

Comment: Not only `plot`, but this allow Pylance to understand all methods of axes inside the array. This is a more suitable answer.