# Is there a way to annotate the dtype of a numpy array? (PEP 3107)

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, annotations

When working with numpy arrays I would like to annotate the dtype of the array. It's possible to annotate a parameter as `np.ndarray` but this doesn't say anything about it's dtype which would be important in some cases.

I would like to be able to say something like this:

```py
def foo(bar: np.ndarray(dtype=np.float32)):
    pass
```

Comment: Are tou using something to test the annotations, e.g. `mypy`?

Comment: Yes, in my case it's PyCharm.

Comment: Seems relevant: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35673895/type-hinting-annotation-pep-484-for-numpy-ndarray/35688036#35688036, as well as this chat https://github.com/numpy/numpy/issues/7370