# Adding annotation to Numpy array for Mypy annotation checks

Tags: python, numpy, mypy

I would like to add annotation to my Numpy arrays so I can use the Mypy library to type check, in a similar way as I do, for example, with lists:

`l: list[int] = [0,1, 2]` (correct according to Mypy)
`l: list[int] = [0.0,0.1, 0.2]` (Mypy throws an error)

However, if I use a similar method with Numpy arrays, Mypy never throws errors:

`import numpy.typing as npt`
`a: [npt.NDArray[np.int64] = np.array([0.1, 0.2, 0.3])` (no error according to Mypy)

I can even do things like this:
`a[0] = 2.0` and Mypy does not throw errors.

I based the Mypy typing for Numpy arrays on this post: [Specific type annotation for NumPy ndarray using mypy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66349242/specific-type-annotation-for-numpy-ndarray-using-mypy)

It seems that I’m not using the correct typing for Numpy, so I experimented with different ways of adding typing for Numpy arrays:

`a: np.ndarray[Any, np.int64] = np.array([0,1,0])` (Mypy returns that the Type argument must be a subtype of numpy.dtype[Any] and that there are incompatible types in the assignment)
`a: np.ndarray[Any, np.int64] = np.array([0,1,0], dtype= np.int64)` (Mypy returns that the Type argument must be a subtype of numpy.dtype[Any] and that there are incompatible types in the assignment)

Can someone explain what the correct way of adding type annotations to numpy arrays is?

I’m using mypy version 0.910 and numpy version 1.23.1

Comment: You missed the line in the linked answer about `the matching dtype to the factory on the right side.`.  `mypy` doesn't check that `np.array([...])` produces the annotated dtype.  That's a dynamic result, one that a static type analyzer can't handle.  `mypy` handles `[1, 2, 3]` because that's easy check as a list of ints.  `[0.1, 0.2, 0.3]` is a list of floats, which is then passed to `np.array` factory, which in turn (with complex `numpy` code), produces an array.

Comment: Please upgrade `mypy` if possible - 1.1.0 was released recently, and since 0.910 they added a noticeable number of bugfixes and features. `npt.NDArray[np.int64]` is a proper annotations, do you have plugin enabled?

Comment: @hpaulj thank you for your reply! Do you mean that it is not possible to check the types of a numpy array as we do with types in a list?

Comment: @SUTerliakov thank you for your reply! I will update to the new release. What exactly do you mean with the plugin?

Comment: [This one](https://numpy.org/devdocs/reference/typing.html)