# Type hint 2D numpy array

Tags: python, numpy, type-hinting

As a follow-up to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35673895/type-hinting-annotation-pep-484-for-numpy-ndarray) I have a function that will return a 2D `numpy.array` of fixed columns but variable rows

```
import numpy.typing as npt

def example() -> npt.ArrayLike:
    data = np.array([[1,2,3],
                     [4,5,6],
                     ...,
                     [x,y,z]])
```

How can I specifically hint that the returned array will be `3` columns by `N` (variable) rows?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Type hinting / annotation (PEP 484) for numpy.ndarray](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35673895/type-hinting-annotation-pep-484-for-numpy-ndarray)

Comment: [Numpy Typing](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/typing.html#module-numpy.typing) documentation doesn't say anything about possible dimensions. So maybe you cannot easily currently. However with [Python new type](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#distinct), you may be able to achieve a custom solution. Depends on what you want to do with the type hints, I guess.

Comment: There is an answer there that specifies the shape of the numpy array...

Comment: @SamuelNLP, that link was asked years ago before the addition of the `numpy` typing module.  I've had to add a big disclaimer to the accepted answer because people kept giving it a thumbs down.  Stick with a reference to the current `numpy` developments.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

*Update on October 24, 2022*

This is still not possible currently, but according to [this comment on a Numpy GitHub issue](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/issues/16544#issuecomment-1058675773), it will be possible once mypy supports [PEP 646](https://peps.python.org/pep-0646/). Please see [the relevant issue on mypy's GitHub repo](https://github.com/python/mypy/issues/12280). That issue is open at the time of writing.

Python 3.11 has been released today with support for PEP646. Once mypy supports PEP646, users will be able to type-hint the shapes of Numpy arrays.

---

*Older answer*

It seems like it is not possible to type-hint the shape (or data type) of a `numpy.ndarray` at this point (September 13, 2022). There are, however, some recent pull requests to numpy working towards this goal.

- https://github.com/numpy/numpy/pull/17719

  > makes the `np.ndarray` class generic w.r.t. its shape and dtype: `np.ndarray[~Shape, ~DType]`

  However, an explicit non-goal of that PR is to make runtime-subscriptable aliases for `numpy.ndarray`. According to that PR, those changes will come in later PRs.
- https://github.com/numpy/numpy/issues/16544

  Issue discussing typing support for shapes. It is still open at the time of writing.

[PEP 646](https://peps.python.org/pep-0646/) is related to this and has been accepted into Python 3.11. According to [numpy/numpy issue #16544](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/issues/16544), one will be able to type-hint shape and data type of arrays after type checkers like mypy add support for PEP 646.

---

This is possible to do with the [`nptyping` package](https://github.com/ramonhagenaars/nptyping), but that is not part of numpy.

```py
from typing import Any
from nptyping import NDArray

# Nx3 array with Any data type.
NDArray[(Any, 3), Any]
```

Comment: Did numpy land support for PEP 646, could provide some examples?

Comment: Is there an update on this?

Comment: @Royi - sort of... see https://github.com/numpy/numpy/issues/16544#issuecomment-1804251364 feel free to update this answer