# Type alias for TensorFlow shape

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, pytorch, python-typing

I commonly pass around shapes throughout my model code.

1. Is there a type alias for shapes I can import from TensorFlow/Keras?
2. If not, what would be the correct type hint for a shape?

What I currently have is this, can I do better?

```py
from collections.abc import Sequence
from typing import TypeAlias

Shape: TypeAlias = Sequence[int | None]


input_shape: Shape = (None, 32, 32, 3)  # Batch of RGB images from CIFAR100 dataset
```

---

Edit: I know [`numpy.typing.NDArray`](https://numpy.org/doc/1.22/reference/typing.html) uses `typing.Any` as a type alias for shape.  I am hoping to do better than this.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Type hint 2D numpy array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66657117/type-hint-2d-numpy-array)

Comment: Following those links and into the PR, you eventually come upon [this line](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/pull/17719/files#diff-db8483d86d7214c860f5426db5b4f219d991f60ea325f49040e6e06d5278bb03R1446) where it has `_ShapeType = TypeVar("_ShapeType", bound=Any)`.  I was hoping for something better than a nickname for `typing.Any`

Comment: there's an [RFC](https://github.com/tensorflow/community/blob/master/rfcs/20200211-tf-types.md#types-created-by-this-rfc) for tensorflow types. It mentions `Shape` but I can't see it in the [API](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/types). Notably, `def shape(self):` is [untyped](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/python/types/core.py)

Comment: are you asking if the type alias for tensor shapes is correct, or if you can instances of tensor shapes in types? @AlexanderL.Hayes I think OP means the first in which case this isn't a duplicate

Comment: Okay so TensorFlow doesn't currently (November 2022) have a built-in type alias I can import, that's alright.  I think then @joel I am wondering if you can confirm the `TypeAlias` I suggested above is good, or can you propose a more optimal one?

Comment: you may need to add `tf.TensorShape`, though that may be a `Sequence[int | None]`