# Delaunay triangulation with wrapped dimension?

Tags: python, scipy, geometry, computational-geometry, delaunay

I'd like to do Delaunay triangulation in the space of 2d poses (x, y, yaw) - where yaw is an angle in [0, 2*pi).  I guess I need to define some scaling factor between meters and radians to make the problem well defined - lets say it's 1 for now.

I've been using [scipy.spatial.Delaunay](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.spatial.Delaunay.html) for Delaunay triangulation but they don't seem to support wrapped dimensions (the yaw).  Is there some sort of trick or way to massage the input (or some open-source code) to make it work?

Comment: You can simulate the wrapped dimension by replicating the period infinitely. Then the Delaunay triangulation of a period should do the trick. As an infinite replication is not practical :-) it is not impossible that a single replica on both sides will be enough.

Comment: Anyway, this idea of mixing distances and angles seems suspicious and probably reveals an XY problem. Also notice that the triangulation is in fact a tetrahedrization.

Comment: Yeah, @Peter, what's the problem you're solving?

Comment: The end-problem is to find a path that traverses a set of poses efficiently.  Goal of the delaunay triangulation is to find neighbouring poses, turning it into a graph so it can be treated as a Travelling Salesman Problem.  Because of limited turning radius, yaw of each pose affects the chosen path.

Comment: Thanks Yves - yes, single replica on both sides seems like the way to go.  It looks like it could even be less - with a half-wrap on each side - just do `wrapped_yaw = yaw+2*pi if yaw < pi else yaw-2*pi`.  I'll post a solution if I get it working.  

Alternative approach was to use `cos(yaw)` and `sin(yaw)` as inputs, but then we have a 4d problem and probably a lot more computational complexity for the hyper-tetrahedrization.

Answer (score 0):

Well, did it with wrapping.  I haven't tested correctness, but this seems to work.

(The array annotation you can remove or copy from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64032593/851699))

```
def get_delaunay_pose_neighbours(poses: Array['N',3], meters_per_turn: float) -> Array['P,2', int]:
    """ Do delaunay triangulation in pose-space.  The trickiness here is in doing it correctly for the wrapped yaw dimension
    """
    yaws = poses[:, [2]]  # poses are (x, y, yaw)
    wrapped_poses = np.hstack([poses[:, :2], yaws + np.where(yaws < np.pi, 2 * np.pi, -2 * np.pi)])
    vertices = np.vstack([poses, wrapped_poses]) * (1, 1, meters_per_turn)
    pairs = get_delaunay_neighbour_indices(vertices).T
    pairs = pairs % len(poses)  # Collapse the wrapping
    pairs = pairs[pairs[:, 0] != pairs[:, 1]]  # Remove self-pairs
    pairs = get_unique_rows(pairs)  # Remove duplicate pairs (from the wrapping)
    return pairs

def get_delaunay_neighbour_indices(vertices: Array['N,D', int]) -> Array['2,P', int]:
    """
    Find each pair of neighbouring vertices in the Delaunay triangulation.
    # TODO: See if we can get better performance.  This takes about 30ms on a BPearl Scan.
    :param vertices: The vertices of the points to perform Delaunay triangulation on
    :return: The pairs of indices of vertices
    """
    tri = Delaunay(vertices)
    spacing_indices, neighbours = tri.vertex_neighbor_vertices
    ixs = np.zeros((2, len(neighbours)), dtype=int)
    ixs[0, spacing_indices[1:np.argmax(spacing_indices)]] = 1  # The argmax is unfortuantely needed when multiple final elements the same
    ixs[0, :] = np.cumsum(ixs[0, :])
    ixs[1, :] = neighbours
    return ixs

def get_unique_rows(arr: Array['N,D', float]) -> Array['M,D', float]:
    """ Get unique rows, given the arrays"""
    row_view = collapse_rows_into_values(arr)
    values = np.unique(row_view)
    values_recast = values.view(arr.dtype).reshape(len(values), -1)
    return values_recast

def collapse_rows_into_values(arr: Array['N,D', Any]) -> Array['N', Any]:
    """ Collapse rows into single values.  Useful for finding unique rows with np.unique """
    return np.ascontiguousarray(arr).view(np.dtype((np.void, arr.dtype.itemsize * np.prod(arr.shape[1:])))).ravel()
```